# Declare C++ methods outside of class?

Tags: c++, macros

I'm in a situation where I have a C++ file with a macro that generates several functions on the fly:

```
#define FUNC_GEN(x,y,z) \
int x(int arg1, float arg2) \
{ \
    .... \
} \
\
int y(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) \
{ \
    .... \
} \
\
double z(int arg1, float arg2) \
{ \
    .... \
} \

FUNC_GEN(func1,func2,func3) // Hundreds of these
```

This generates something like:

```
int func1(int arg1, float arg2)
{
    ....
}

int func2(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    ....
}

double func1(int arg1, float arg2)
{
    ....
}
```

I have hundreds of these scattered throughout a file. What I'd like to do is change FUNC_GEN to make the generated functions methods of a particular class. The issue I have is that my understanding is that the functions must be declared with the class definition. Because this is actually generating functions on the fly, this isn't easy to insert in the class definition.

Is there a way in C++ to change this macro to make these methods class members? I'm only aware of one way (the one I'm avoiding) which is to hunt down all of these macros and manually add them myself to the class definition.

My naive approach was to do this:

```
#define FUNC_GEN(x,y,z) \
private int myclass::x(int arg1, float arg2) \
{ \
    .... \
} \
\
private int myclass::y(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) \
{ \
    .... \
} \
\
private double myclass::z(int arg1, float arg2) \
{ \
    .... \
} \
```

But because they are not declared with the class, the compiler refuses to let that build ("Error: class has no member").

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just invoke the macro within the class definition? Anyway this smells badly, IMHO.

Comment: What is the reason why this is done, what does it achieve?

Comment: _"I have hundreds of these scattered throughout a file"_ wooooooah why??

Comment: Wait a second. You declare and define hundreds of the same three functions with different names in a file? Why would you do that in the first place?

Comment: Would using templates instead of the preprocessor work?

Comment: Your issue is using the access specifier before the method name.  Remove it.  The compiler already knows the accessibility from the class declaration.

Comment: In all seriousness, why do you need identical functions available under *hundreds* of different names? Perhaps you're not telling us something. Please tell us what is different about the implementations of those functions, then perhaps we can offer a completely different solution.

Answer (score 4):

The definitions of class methods can be anywhere outside of the class.  When you define a class method outside the class, you need to prefix the method name with the class name and scope resolution operator.

**The important part is not to use the scope access keywords, such as `private`, `protected` or `public`.**

Here is an example:

```
class Kitten
{
  public:
    void run ();
    void hiss ();
};

void Kitten::run()
{
  //...
}

void Kitten::hiss()
{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest solution is defining the functions inside the class:

```
class myclass
{
  private:
  FUNC_GEN(func1,func2,func3) // Hundreds of these
};
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer OP already knows, and wishes to avoid: "hunt down all of these macros and manually add them myself to the class definition."

Comment: Wishes don't change the language rules.

Answer (score 0):

Declarations for all member functions *must* be included in the class definition. You can either:

- define the functions inside the class declaration with the macro, or
- create another macro that will just declare the functions but not define them, and put that inside the class declaration.

Comment: This also seems to be the answer OP already knows, and wishes to avoid: "hunt down all of these macros and manually add them myself to the class definition."